# PHP foreach loop unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, mysqli

What I am trying to do here is write a code to update my database automatically; for those derived attributes. Here is the part of the code where I try to grab all the rows in an array:

```
include("dbConnect.php");
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from nw_order;");
if($results) 
    foreach($results as $hgh)
        $resultArray[] = $results->fetch_row();

else
    die("Query failed");

foreach($resultArray as $row) {
    foreach($row as $field)
        print $field." ";
    print "<br>";
}
```

The foreach grab only even numbered rows for some reason.
Also, trying to substitute foreach with while gives me memory shortage error. I am so tired I will check in tomorrow. If you can help me out that will be awesome.

Comment: it's impossible to help you out without data

Comment: Why do you loop through the `$results` variable to fill up the `$resultArray` variable to loop through it again?

Comment: that's NOT how you fetch rows from a result. the foreach() grabs one row, then you simply throw away $hgh and fetch ANOTHER row with the fetch_row() call. if you insiste on foreach, then at least change it to `foreach(...) { $resultArray[] = $hgh; }`

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. I knew this was a bit off somehow.

Answer (score 1):

```
include("dbConnect.php");
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from nw_order;");
$rows = array();
if($results) {
  $rows = $results->fetch_all();
}

foreach($rows as $row) {
  foreach($row as $field) {
        echo $field." ";
  }
  echo "<br>";
}
```

But actually I'd rather neither "SELECT *  " nor print all fields regardlessly.
I find things more maintainable when they are more explicit.

Comment: I'd suggest that if you clean/improve his code, do it completely. One should use brackets for every conditional or loop statement. Someday someone else mantains this code and in a hurry adds another line to the `if($results)`-block and wonders why its not working. And another  post like this will be born :).

Comment: :D yes these posts keep being born all the time

Comment: Ok. Thank you. This looks nice

Comment: By the way, can you explain why using while($results) causes memory shortage?